# Openstack keystone token issue. Failed to discover available identity versions

Tags: apache2, openstack, keystone

Im attempting to setup keystone identity service on virtualized Ubuntu 20.4 via Windows Hyper-V on Windows 10.

I followed the instructions on: https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/pike/install/index-ubuntu.html very carefully & attempted this 4 times from scratch with a new VM.

However, all calls to OpenStack web service API either via curl, or command line result in some type of 404 Error.

Here my detailed steps (not including VM setup):

1. Install & Setup MySQL for keystone:

[image]

[image]

2. apt install keystone :

[image]

3. configure keystone:

[image]

4. fernet setup:

[image]

5. Bootstrap keystone:
   [image]
6. Apache2 setup:

In /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
Set `ServerName controller`

7. source confif file

[image]

8. check port 5000.

[image]

9. set local host name resolution:
   [image]
10. Start apache. `service apache2 restart`

Here is the issue:

Attempt # 1 - Using curl to call keystone API (404):

Attempt # 2 - Using openstack command line tool, again (404):

[image]

Troubleshooting:

Keystone logs look good with no error:
[image]

Furthermore, apache2 is running as I can see default server page:

[image]

So why cant keystone API be reached?

Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

export these variables and test again

```
export OS_AUTH_VERSION=3
export OS_ENDPOINT_TYPE=internalURL
export OS_INTERFACE=internalURL
export OS_AUTH_TYPE=password
export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
export OS_NO_CACHE=1
```

check your wsgi and apache2 vhost config too, to make sure apache will redircet it correctly

Answer (score 0):

would you please check if **libapache2-mod-WSGI** is installed as it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/pike/install/keystone-install-ubuntu.html#configure-the-apache-http-server)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xHE4.png)